# How to translate ng2-smart-table action columnTitle and action title

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate, ng2-smart-table

How to translate ng2-smart-table action columnTitle and action title.
I was trying to resolve translation issue for Acknowledgement, But still not sure why it isn't working

```
violationSettings:any = {};
  initTableSettings(): void {
    this.violationSettings = {
      actions: {
        columnTitle: this.translateService.instant('acknowledgement'),
        custom: [
          {
            name: 'Checkmark',
            title: `<span class="custom-checkmark">
                    <i class="nb-checkmark "></i>
                  </span>`
          }
        ]
      },
      columns: {
        vesselName: {
          title: this.translateService.instant('vessel-name'),
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
    };
  }
  constructor(
    private theme: NbThemeService,
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.initTableSettings();
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(next => {
      this.initTableSettings();
    })
  }
```

Comment: I'd first check if the provided translation key is correct (perhaps it's a nested key). If it is, then I'd see where you're initialing your `actions` object. Perhaps it's being initialized too early for `translateService` to be ready itself. In that case there's always the option to load the translation asynchronously (ie. `translateService.getTranslation('key').subscribe(() => // do something)`).

Comment: @AldinBradaric I've created a function in which I've assigned this action and call this function in constructor and also call the same function when translate onLangChange, all the header of table was translated but action customTitle was not translated

Comment: Could you post that code as well then?

Comment: @AldinBradaric see now

Comment: The code itself looks fine. Does the problem remain if you try to assign a different translation key to `columnTitle`?

Comment: Yeah, I've assign different key but same issue occur